# Can't install windows 10 - "Couldn't find info for boot disk [1]"

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, partitioning

Sorry for posting the logs as a photo, I couldn't copy it from the PC. I used to have Ubuntu Server installed on that computer and I decided erase everything and install win 10. In the window where I choose the partition, I get:

```
We Couldn’t Create a New Partition Error in Windows 10
```

I SHIFT+F10 into the terminal and opened %WINDIR%/panther/setupact.log. The first error I see is:

```
Couldn't find info for boot disk
```

Secure boot is disabled, I tried switching from RAID to the other mode, tried switching the boot order - nothing helps. I also tried to manually create an NTFS partition with the disk utility - still nothing. Please help :(

[image]

Comment: Try formatting the disk first with FDISK

Comment: BTW, did the machine *ever* have a licensed Windows 10 installation? You might need to activate Windows with a key. Also, consider you'll get less than one year of security updates on Win 10 before EOL.

Comment: And, by the looks of it, you really need to study a bit about UEFI and UEFI mode, and about what that entails in terms of requirements for Windows, namely GTP. Linux is a lot more "flexible".